# Does a (closed) meagre set have empty interior?

Tags: general-topology

Does a meagre set have empty interior? And if it is closed or compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the topological space. For example, let the topological space be $X=\mathbb Q$ with the euclidian topology. Then $X$ is itself a meagre set because it's the countable union of singletons.

Comment: Ok, so it is not true neither in general neither if it is closed. What about if it compact?

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo in $\Bbb Q$, $K= \{\frac1n: n=1,2,3,\ldots \} \cup\{0\}$ is compact and meagre.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It has empty interior, isn't it?

Comment: In $\Bbb Q$ a compact set always has empty interior.

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo If you are content with my answer, please upvote and check it as done. Thanks.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So it is not a conterexample to my question

Comment: @amsmath Your answer answers only half question. I can upvote it, but not accept it.

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo A countable cofinite space is a compact meagre space with non-empty interior.  If $X$ is Hausdorff, however, a compact meagre set has empty interior.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Could you justify your last assertion?